# How to link 2 items from the same array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English. English isn't my main language.
So, I have this data,

```
datamhs = 
np.array([["x", 85, "22222221"],
["y", 85, "22222222"],
["z", 70, "22222223"],
["a", 90, "22222224"],
["b", 60, "22222225"],
["c", 90, "22222226"]])
```

Is there a way to reference each row with itself? For example, I want to make x has value of 85 and uid of 22222221.

I want to make a function that check if x has value of 85 and/or has uid of 22222221.

I'm sorry if it hard to understand I really don't know how to write it. Thanks for answering.

I'm trying

```
def name():
  if x in datamhs[:,0]:
    if y in datamhs[:,1]:
      print(x)
      print(y)
```

It's print out an error which y not defined. When I try to define it with,

```
y = datamhs[:,1]
```

Then it just show up with a list of the value.

I want to input x, then checking if x has the value of y.

Comment: maybe add a new column to the data with this unique ID

Comment: Can you share your desired output?

Comment: for example, from row 1, when I run the name(), I want to get,
x = x 
y = 85 
z = 22222221

from row 4, i want to get,
x = a
y = 90
z = 22222224

Answer (score 0):

Where do x and y come from? I can't understand

Maybe you should try something like that

```
def name():
  if 'x' in datamhs[:,0]:
    if 'y' in datamhs[:,1]:
      print(datamhs[:,0])
      print(datamhs[:,1])
```

The python interpreter nothing knows about x and y if you have not yet defined them.

Comment: that's not working. it says it need to be int or slices, not tuples.